# automapper - ignore mapping if property type is different with same property name - C#

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

How can I ignore mapping if property type is different with same property name?
By default it's throwing error.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityAttribute, LeadManagementService.LeadEntityAttribute>();

Model = Mapper.Map<EntityAttribute, LeadManagementService.LeadEntityAttribute>(EntityAttribute);
```

I know a way to specify the property name to ignore but that's not what I want.

```
  .ForMember(d=>d.Field, m=>m.Ignore());
```

Because in the future I might add new properties. So i need to ignore mapping for all properties with different data types.

Comment: Have you tried .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(IsValidType))); Please see my answer for example source code.

Answer (score 5):

You should use ignore for properties that should be ignored:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityAttribute, LeadManagementService.LeadEntityAttribute>()
     ForMember(d=>d.FieldToIgnore, m=>m.Ignore());
```

Comment: I may add new properties in the future. so i need to ignore mapping for all properties with different data type

Comment: You cannot. All you can do is to write autotest on configuration, that will alert you if problem field is added

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ForAllMembers()` to setup the appropriate mapping condition:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<EntityAttribute, LeadEntityAttribute>().ForAllMembers(memberConf =>
    {
        memberConf.Condition((ResolutionContext cond) => cond.DestinationType == cond.SourceType);
    });
}
```

You can also apply it globally using `ForAllMaps()`:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    // register your maps here
    cfg.CreateMap<A, B>();

    cfg.ForAllMaps((typeMap, mappingExpr) =>
    {
        var ignoredPropMaps = typeMap.GetPropertyMaps();

        foreach (var map in ignoredPropMaps)
        {
            var sourcePropInfo = map.SourceMember as PropertyInfo;
            if (sourcePropInfo == null) continue;

            if (sourcePropInfo.PropertyType != map.DestinationPropertyType)
                map.Ignore();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried the 2nd option `ForAllMaps()` and am getting an error in the last line for `map.Ignore()`. `Ignore` method is not found. Getting this error => `CS1061 'PropertyMap' does not contain a definition for 'Ignore' and no extension method 'Ignore' accepting a first argument of type 'PropertyMap' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` Thoughts?

Comment: @Shiva, Try `map.Ignored = true` instead. Perhaps they changed the API since the answer was written.

Comment: If you are using AutoMapper 8.0, replace GetPropertyMaps() with PropertyMaps and DestinationPropertyType with DestinationType.

Answer (score 0):

One way to process all properties for type is to use .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(IsValidType))). I have used new syntax for AutoMapper usage, but it should work even with old syntax.

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;

namespace TestAutoMapper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Car, CarDto>()
                .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(IsValidType))); //and how to conditionally ignore properties
            var car = new Car
            {
                VehicleType = new AutoType
                {
                    Code = "001DXT",
                    Name = "001 DTX"
                },
                EngineName = "RoadWarrior"
            };

            IMapper mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
            var carDto = mapper.Map<Car, CarDto>(car);
            Console.WriteLine(carDto.EngineName);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static bool IsValidType(ResolutionContext arg)
        {
            var isSameType = arg.SourceType== arg.DestinationType; //is source and destination type is same?
            return isSameType;
        }
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public AutoType VehicleType { get; set; } //same property name with different type
        public string EngineName { get; set; }
    }

    public class CarDto
    {
        public string VehicleType { get; set; } //same property name with different type
        public string EngineName { get; set; }
    }

    public class AutoType
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: "ForAllMembers" cannot be applied to operand of type void ..this error is coming

Comment: Can you post more details or update your question with what you have tried?