# Ignore mapping for all members with different types and same name, using newest version of Automapper(6.1.1)

Tags: c#, automapper-6

How can I ignore mapping if some properties have different type with same name? By default it's throwing error.
I found some answers for an older versions of automapper but they are not working with the newest.

For example one property is string the other is bool but they both have the same name. The behaviour i want is to ignore them(not try to map them).

Comment: What do you mean "different types"? Like one is a DateTime and one is a string, or something like that? And what do you mean by "ignore mappings", you want to exclude them? Please edit your question to show an example of what you're trying to do, and explain why it's "not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078323/automapper-ignore-mapping-if-property-type-is-different-with-same-property-nam)

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>();

    cfg.ForAllMaps((typeMap, mappingExpr) =>
    {
        var ignoredPropMaps = typeMap.GetPropertyMaps();

        foreach (var map in ignoredPropMaps)
        {
            var sourcePropInfo = map.SourceMember as PropertyInfo;
            if (sourcePropInfo == null) continue;
            if (sourcePropInfo.PropertyType != map.DestinationPropertyType)
                map.Ignored = true;
        }
    });
});

Class1 src = new Class1()
{
    TestProperty = "A"
};
Class2 dest = Mapper.Map<Class1, Class2>(src);
```

Test classes:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string TestProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public bool TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's the idea, but probably the code would look better with ForAllPropertyMaps.

Comment: Right, but I don't want to invest to much time, when OP doesn't make the effort to post a question with detailed information ;)

Comment: The answer is what i was looking for! Worked great!