# Strict type validation of properties in Automapper

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, automapper

Is it possible to set some kind of global configuration that would cause mapping or validation process fail when some properties of mapped objects have same name, but have different types?

**Source/destination types**

```
public class UserData1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class UserData2
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping configuration**

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<UserData1, UserData2>();
});
```

**Expected behavior**

Either AssertConfigurationIsValid or Map should trigger some kind of validation exception when types of mapping properties are not same.

**Actual behavior**

int property is mapped to string without exception.

**Steps to reproduce**

```
// Passes OK
 Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

 // Mapping is successful
 var user2 = Mapper.Map<UserData2>(new UserData1 { Id = 156 });
```

Comment: Could you include the example in full instead of the link. Links may not work in the future.

Comment: You can add custom validations through an extension point. See [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/7a00700de61cd3234b6a6eb4bf0f6bbe402369b1/src/UnitTests/ConfigurationValidation.cs#L30).

Comment: Added the sample from the closed git issue.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - My initial idea was to use custom validator, but it appear that it will have more complex code

Comment: Well, I don't know. It integrates cleanly with validation. What's complex about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no build in solution available, but it can be achieved using custom configuration.

Something like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<UserData1, UserData2>();
    ...
    cfg.ForAllMaps((typeMap, mappingExpr) =>
    {
        foreach (var map in typeMap.PropertyMaps) {
            var sourcePropInfo = map.SourceMember as PropertyInfo;
            var destPropInfo = map.DestinationMember as PropertyInfo;

            if (sourcePropInfo == null || destPropInfo == null) continue;

            if (sourcePropInfo.PropertyType != destPropInfo.PropertyType)
                throw new Exception("Wrong property type!");
        }
    });
});
```

As reference was used this old post and updated to work with new version of automapper
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38080647/1703620

Comment: Thank you. Will check this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Using Artyom's answer as inspiration, I wrote a unit test to constrain these implicit type conversions to the few scenarios that we're okay with.

The approach is to look up all property mappings that don't have an explicit mapping, and filter out the few scenarios that we want to allow.

an XUnit test:

```
        [Fact]
        public void AllMappedPropertiesAreSameTypeOrAreMappedExplicitly()
        {
            ServiceCollection theCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            theCollection.AddMssAutoMapper();

            IMapper theMapper = BuildProductionMapper();

            //Store all explicit mappings for easy lookup
            System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<(Type SourceType, Type DestType)> theExplicitMappings =
                theMapper.ConfigurationProvider.GetAllTypeMaps()
                .Select( map => (map.SourceType, map.DestinationType) )
                .ToHashSet();

            var theIllegalMaps =
            from typeMap in theMapper.ConfigurationProvider.GetAllTypeMaps()
            from propMap in typeMap.PropertyMaps
            let sourceType = propMap.SourceType
            let destType = propMap.DestinationType
            let bothTypes = new[] { sourceType, destType }
            where sourceType != null && destType != null
            where sourceType != destType

            //Anything that's explicitly mapped is permitted
            where !theExplicitMappings.Contains( (sourceType, destType) )

            //enums to string and vice versa is permitted
            where !( sourceType.IsEnum || sourceType == typeof( string ) && destType.IsEnum || destType == typeof( string ) )

            //mapping from one collection to another is okay
            where !bothTypes.All( type => type.IsAssignableTo( typeof( IEnumerable ) ) )
            select new
            {
                SourceType = typeMap.SourceType,
                DestinationType = typeMap.DestinationType,
                SourceMemberName = propMap.SourceMember.Name,
                DestMemberName = propMap.DestinationMember.Name,
                SourceMemberType = sourceType,
                DestinationMemberType = destType
            };
            var illegalMapsList = theIllegalMaps.ToList();
            foreach( var illegalMap in illegalMapsList )
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine( $"Found disallowed property mapping from '{illegalMap.SourceType}.{illegalMap.SourceMemberName}' to '{illegalMap.DestinationType}.{illegalMap.DestMemberName}'" );
                Console.Out.WriteLine( $"Property name: {illegalMap.SourceMemberName}" );
                Console.Out.WriteLine( $"implicit mapping from {illegalMap.SourceMemberType} to {illegalMap.DestinationMemberType} is not allowed." );
                Console.Out.WriteLine( $"Please map these types explicitly." );
            }

            if( illegalMapsList.Any() )
            {
                throw new Exception( "One or more ambiguous mappings were found that need to be handled explicitly.  See console output for details." );
            }
        }
```